# linode.com did not encrypt this message

Tags: linux, email, postfix, gmail, linode

When I send a mail using Contact Form 7 WordPress plugin on my website, I get Linode.com did not encrypt this message in the Gmail Error in Gmail. I also see a Red padlock.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me.

**Here are the steps.**

1. Connect to your server as `root`.
   *I used Filezilla*
2. Navigate to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. 
   *In filezilla, first I had to click the `/` in the directory to access these folders*
3. Add the following lines in `main.cf` file as folows

```
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

4. Done! The message is now gone.

[Source](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/10846/gmail-message-is-not-crypted-but-its-not-true)